# Find and replace excel VBA trouble

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a Excel VBA project in which I have created a button to find and replace the value in the worksheet depending on the user input, where user will provide a new hardware name, a quantity and the sheet name in which the new value needs to be updated. The hardware name is a unique value, so the update of the quantity should happen depending on the hardware name.

The problem I am facing is that, when I try to update the values, the hardware name is getting updated properly but where as while updating the quantity it is not only updating the quantity of that particular hardware name but is updating all the quantity that matches the old quantity.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
If .ComboBox1.Value <> vbNullString Then
         sName = .ComboBox1.Text 'is combobox name

         If Len(.OldHW.Value) > 0 And Len(.NewHW.Value) > 0 Then
             sOldText = .OldHW.Text 'OldHW and NewHW are textbox names
             sNewText = .NewHW.Text         

             With Worksheets(sName)
                 .Cells.replace what:=sOldText, Replacement:=sNewText, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                     ReplaceFormat:=False                         

             End With
         End If


        If Len(.Oldqty.Value) > 0 And Len(.Newqty.Value) > 0 Then
            qOldText = .Oldqty.Text
           qNewText = .Newqty.Text

             With Worksheets(sName)
                 .Cells.replace what:=qOldText, Replacement:=qNewText, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                     ReplaceFormat:=False

             End With
         End If    
     End If
 End With
```

Please any input will be greatly appreciated...

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing to connect your two replace operations: the first just looks for a name and the second for a quantity.  You'd be better off looping through the rows and finding each instance of the name and then checking the quantity on the same row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are doing two seperate and independant search/replace operations.  The result will be exactly what you describe, all matching `qOldText` values will be replaced.

The correct approach would be when you search for the `sOldText` return a reference to the cell it finds

```
Set oCell = Nothing
Set oCell = sName.UsedRange.Find what:=sOldText, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
```

Then replace sOldText in the located cell and qOldText in a cell relative to the located cell.  The position of the Qty cell must depend on the sheet layout.  For example if its in the same row, next column use:

```
If Not oCell is Nothing then
    oCell =  sNewText 
    oCell.Offset(0,1) = qNewText
End If
```

From your question it would seem qOldText has no use, unless there is somthing I've missed.